# Basic Game Model in Scripting Language

Tags: game, lua

I've been working with Lua for a little bit, and I have finally come up with some code that can be extended to create the core of a game model.  I come from an object oriented background, so working with Lua is very different for me.

The purpose of this code would be to create the game model for a game with Lua.  Another programming language would load the scripts and then make the calls to create the Game object and to advance the turns.  Any information resulting from a game turn could be passed back to the rendering in the proper programming language.

I would love to hear about any aspect of this code, but I am new to Lua syntax so I am sure I am making rookie mistakes.

**Game.lua**

```
--This syntax loads other scripts, such as Player.lua
local player = require "Player"

local Game = {} -- the table representing the class, which will double as the metatable for the instances
Game.__index = Game -- failed table lookups on the instances should fallback to the class table, to get methods

-- syntax equivalent to "MyClass.new = function..."
function Game.new()
    local self = setmetatable({}, Game)

    self.players = {}

    self.currentTurn = 0

    return self
end

--Adding players to the game
function Game.addPlayers(self, numPlayers)
    --i has to be set to 1 for it to work properly
    for i = 1, numPlayers, 1 do
        self:addPlayer()
    end
end

function Game.addPlayer(self)
  table.insert(self.players, player.new(6))
end

--Advancing and reporting the game turns
function Game.advanceTurn(self)
  self.currentTurn = self.currentTurn + 1
end

function Game.getTurnNumber(self)
  return self.currentTurn
end

--test function to access player data
function Game.reportPlayers(self)
  for key,value in pairs(self.players) do
    print(key)
  end
end

--create the game "instance"
local game = Game.new()
game:addPlayers(2)

--these types of commands would be sent to Lua by a proper programming language
game:advanceTurn()
print(game:getTurnNumber())
game:advanceTurn()
print(game:getTurnNumber())
game:reportPlayers()
```

**Player.lua**

```
Player = {} -- the table representing the class, which will double as the metatable for the instances
Player.__index = Player -- failed table lookups on the instances should fallback to the class table, to get methods

-- syntax equivalent to "MyClass.new = function..."
function Player.new(startingHandSize)
    local self = setmetatable({}, Player)
    self.handSize = startingHandSize
    print(self.handSize)
    return self
end

function Player.set_handSize(self, newHandSize)
    self.handSize = newHandSize
end

function Player.get_handSize(self)
    return self.handSize
end

return Player
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what happens when `self.currentTurn` exceeds `self.numPlayers`. And while we are here, what is the significance of `6` in `game.addPlayer`? Are you having some specific game in mind?

Comment: No specific game in mind, no.  The 6 is the number of starting cards (sorry should have had a comment or variable to indicate that).  Nothing intentional happens if self.currentTurn exceeds self.numPlayers so I did not mean to give that impression.  If something is happening, it is not supposed to be.  The calls at the bottom of the Game.lua script are just examples of the types of calls that will be made when the game is fleshed out.

Comment: Why I was asking about a specific game - I know just one _card_ game with an _initial hand size_ of 6 (and its variants which do not fit a round robin turn model).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't notice any major issues with your code.

- Use `_name` naming for private variables, since everything is **global** (and thus, *accessible*) by default in lua. You can use the normal variable `name` for getters and setters.
- You can modify the getter (`get_handSize`) and setter (`set_handSize`) a little as functions in lua don't need the parameters:

  ```
  function Player.new( startingHandSize )
      local self = setmetatable( {}, Player )
      self._handSize = startingHandSize
      return self
  end
  function Player:handSize( newHandSize )
      if not newHandSize then return self._handSize end
      self._handSize = newHandSize
  end
  ```

  You can now simply use `player:handSize()` or `player:handSize(n)` for getting and setting the *private* variable.
- Since you are simply inserting new players to `self.players` table, you can iterate using `ipairs` to list them sequentially (depends on your game design).
- You can save a little disk space by using the oop approach of defining functions instead of passing `self` every time.

---

That much was a basic approach to oop in lua. Now, extending the concept, you can use closures for **proper private** variables.

```
function Player.new( startingHandSize )
    local self = setmetatable( {}, Player )
    local h = (function()
        local _handSize = startingHandSize
        return function( self, newHandSize )
            if not newHandSize then return _handSize end
            _handSize = newHandSize
        end
    end)()
    self.handSize = h  -- self._handSize will always be nil
    return self
end
```

and in a similar fashion:

```
function Game.new()
    local self = setmetatable({}, Game)
    local c, a = (function()
        local _turn = 0
        return function( self )
            return _turn
        end, function( self )
            _turn = _turn + 1
        end
    end)()
    self.getTurnNumber, self.advanceTurn = c, a  -- self.currentTurn will always be nil
    return self
end
```

Comment: I appreciate the feedback! Do you think that private variables are better than relying on block scoping to limit their scope? I am unsure on this.